# How to display a list of items in android without putting them in a listview?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a view that looks something like this

```
<view>
  <custom-button> //hard-coded
  <custom-button> //hard-coded
  <list>
    // dynamic list contents
  </list>
<view>
```

Where all of the contents are scrollable within the outer view. My first thought was to put it all in a scrollview but apparently you can't place a listview inside a scrollview. What is the best approach to something like this?

Comment: Do you want the list view to expand and not be scrollable, but the parent view to be scrollable ?

Comment: yes so the list itself should not scroll but the entire contents (list along with the buttons) should scroll inside the parent view

Comment: This has already been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing

Comment: @Ashwin flag as duplicate then

Comment: I don't have the privileges to close it as a duplicate yet.

Comment: @Ashwin Yes, I said flag, not close.

Comment: Ah, figured it out now. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions could be use your CustomButtons as a part of `ListView` or `RecyclerView` (first item of list) and use `ViewHolder` pattern for efficiency depending on what kind of other data is in your list.